# PHP - Creating Json with Numeric Keys for Mongo Insert

Tags: php, json, mongodb, php-mongodb

Currently I'm attempting to simulate hours of the day with my keys for inserting into Mongo and I have something along these lines (simplified) setup:

```
for($i=0;$i<23;$i++){
    $returnElement["hours"]["$i"] = array();
    foreach($this->list_of_daily_usage_items as $item){
      /* @var $item DailyUsageItem */
      $returnElement["hours"]["$i"][$item->getLabel()] = $item->getDefaultValue();
    }
  }
```

With this I'm creating something similar to:

```
 [hours] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [labelOne] => 0
                [labelTwo] => 0
            )
        ....
        [23] => Array
            (
                [labelOne] => 0
                [labelTwo] => 0
            )

    )
```

However then when i push to JSON It's converting that to:

```
"hours": [{
    "labelOne": 0,
    "labelTwo": 0,
}, {
    "labelOne": 0,
    "labelTwo": 0,
}]
```

Which normally I would expect; however when I'm attempting to make these numeric keys it's not really what I'm hoping to see..

Is there a way to achieve this short of prepending something like _ to the number to force it to a string?

Thank you

Comment: Ah, the PHP and its array/dictionary duality :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a temporary element to force a PHP Array to be converted a JSON Object

```
 array("_" => "removeme",
    0 => array("hello" => 0,
           "hell0" => 2),
    1 => array("hello" => 0,
           "hell0" => 2),
    2 => array("hello" => 0,
           "hell0" => 2));
```

this will generate

```
{
    "_": "removeme",
    "0": {
        "hello": 0,
        "hell0": 2
    },
    "1": {
        "hello": 0,
        "hell0": 2
    },
    "2": {
        "hello": 0,
        "hell0": 2
    }
}
```

If we combine this with a neato regexp, we just hassled us past PHPs somewhat evil type system:

```
$finejson = preg_replace("/\"_\":\".*\",/", "", $json);
```

which gives us this:

```
{
    "0": {
        "hello": 0,
        "hell0": 2
    },
    "1": {
        "hello": 0,
        "hell0": 2
    },
    "2": {
        "hello": 0,
        "hell0": 2
    }
}
```

Comment: hahaha yea, gotta love php sometimes.. Thanks I'll go this route for now as it's still better than just having a random _ infront of everything.